# Install a package using helm3 for an exisitng non-helm package

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a package installed using kubectl, and it has it's configmaps and resources.

now I am trying to install the same package using helm (with same name and all resources with same names), but on doing helm install, I am getting an error that the resource already exists. Is there a way I can install/override the package using helm which was installed via kubectl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Helm 3 for existing resources deployed with kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177820/use-helm-3-for-existing-resources-deployed-with-kubectl)

Comment: Are you trying to [Use Helm 3 for existing resources deployed with kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177820/use-helm-3-for-existing-resources-deployed-with-kubectl)?  If it's just data objects like ConfigMaps, I'd probably `kubectl delete` them before moving forward with Helm.